# Azure Vmss login through Jumpbox

Tags: powershell, azure, command-line-interface

I deployed an SSH secured Vmss on Azure . I use SSH key to login in a Jumpbox (a VM on Azure withing the same virtual and subnetwork as the Vmss) using Putty. How can I login into my Vmss through my Jumpbox?

[image: My .ssh jumpbox content and you can check my id_rsa files here]

[image: My Vmss back end pool Ip address]

Comment: and whats the problem? open another ssh? also, what does this have to do with azure?

Comment: @SAM.Am If my understanding is right. You want to ssh to your VMSS instance through your jumpbox. It is easy, you could get your instance private IP. Then you could copy ssh private key to jumpbox.  `ssh -i id_rsa user@ip`

Comment: Dear @Walter, You mean I have to use that private IP address at the back end pool Ipaddress. Good. I wil give it a try but what about taht id_rsa private ssh key. Its store into my deployment folder, where shouldl I store it at Azure. ( its' said key vault is the best way but how to refer to it into your command). Thanks

Comment: @SAM.Am Could you export the id_rsa? You create VMSS VM with ssh key, if you want to ssh them, you must have private key.

Comment: @SAM.Am You don't need store private key on Azure.

Comment: Export, how? I used PUTTY and generate a ppk file which i used to login to my jumpbox. exporting id_rsa where exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If my understanding is right, you want to ssh to your VMSS instance through your Jumpbox VM.

If want to do this, according to your description, your jumbox VM and your VMSS instances are in the same Vnet, you could ssh to your instances with private IP. You could find private IPs on Azure Portal. `<Your resource group>-->VMSS load balancer-->Settings-->Backend Pools`.
[image]

You also need copy or upload  your ssh private key to jumpbox VM. Then you could ssh your instances with the following command.

```
ssh -i id_rsa user@private IP
```

Comment: I used my private Ssh Key to login to my jumpbox using Putty. It works fine. Now that I have to login to my VMss, i wonder if I have to store my Private Key to Key vault or load it in another way. something else, my Vmss is attached to a load balancer that has 3 a front end pool of 3 IP addresses , which one should I use to login.

Comment: @SAM.Am You had better know what is [VMSS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machine-scale-sets/virtual-machine-scale-sets-overview). VMSS is not a VM.  VMSS has multiple instances. You could ssh to them. Now, you have 3 instances, you could ssh them all.

Comment: @SAM.Am If you want to ssh your VMSS instances on jumpbox, you need to store the private key on the jumpbox VM.

Comment: you are right, Vmss is not VM. I have to go deep into Vmss before asking my next question. Nonetheless, I know that all my Vm , and my Vmss are deployed with Ssh. Now for id_rsa file how to refer to it to run the SSh connection command.

Comment: @ walter,  my Ssh key is already store  in my jumpbox otherwise I would not be able to connect to it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145517/discussion-between-walter-msft-and-sam-am).

Comment: @SAM.Am your public key is already on your jumpbox. You'll need your private key on the jumpbox in order to SSH to a VMSS VM from it.

Comment: @When you ssh to other VM, don't need `sudo`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks dear @Walter,  Indeed  my JumpBox was deployed with SSH keys , so once i logged in , and I checked  both id_rsa and id_rsa.pub with /.ssh  folder, I just   typed   SSH  User@IpAddress   and logged in immediately. 
 Finaly  I managed to run scripts on my Vmss.   Thanks